# Are our brains just energy conserving systems?

Tags: neuroscience, behaviorism

Is the brain a purely energy conserving system that creates behaviours for conserving the energy distributed to the brain, based on the input of sensory information that our bodies take in?

Comment: I guess the answer to the title would be: no. Because the ultimate energy conservation would be death, and obviously we strive to live, procreate and survive as a species.

Comment: But anything that leads up to death is all about spending tonnes of energy e.g. trying not to die.

Comment: No, if you wanted to conserve energy, your cells would not part after conception. As it stands, your question has been voted to be closed, because obviously we don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I don't understand how you've been answering my question if you didn't understand any of it; it's just a bit of speculation. 2. That doesn't rule out its possibility, though. What if we did that because we actually conserve more by losing some?

Comment: I think you be either alluding to or interested in Friston's free energy principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_energy_principle

Comment: Thanks, that's a really useful resource for me to keep occupied with, but I'm not talking about minimising the surprise (even though that could be an energy efficient behaviour); I am talking about some part of the brain that makes a tree of behaviours as an energy efficient response to whatever coded information the rest of the sensory system provides before hand, so that, overall, the brain is just an energy conserving system. The differences, based only on circumstance, or in the case of other animals, circumstance and different encoding of the senses.